# How to print fields in node.tpl.php?

Tags: nodes, entities

I need to print individual fields from the `$content` variable in `node.tpl.php` file in separate `div` tags. How do I do that and how do I find out what the field's names are?

Comment: Use dsm($node); to find the path to be specified for all pieces of data.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try this

`<?php print render($content['your_field_name']); ?>` this will print that field value .

Comment: Yes but how do I find out what the name of the field is?

Comment: print_r($node);

Comment: or go to admin panel and your content type => managefields => see the machine names of fields , that will be available as your_field_name

Answer (score 6):

enable Devel module and in node-{content-type}.tpl.php

```
    <?php dsm($node); ?>
    <?php dsm($content); ?>
```

you can see all $node fields and content fields

Comment: This doesn't print anything.

Comment: Make sure u have enabled devel module

Comment: <?php print $messages; ?> place this in your page.tpl.php

Comment: How to access this page on the front end node-{content-type}.tpl.php ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) module and use dpm($content) or kpr($content) functions in your node.tpl file. From there you can see all the names and render them the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

I use the [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) Module，to find the field name. It's very useful.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to find the fields available are :

```
<?php
  print render($content);
 ?>
```

in your tpl file. This would display the list of fields available. You can remove these lines later. Then, to print your individual fields you can just do:

```
print render($content['field_blog_pic']); or


 print $title
```

depending on your fields (user pictures, image fields, normal text and so on).